# Singular vs Plural in Names

Tags: singular-vs-plural

This is a tittle of some paper I found online.

> A quantitative theory of the Hounsfield unit and its application to **dual energy** scanning

There are two energies in this CT system. But why the author used **"Dual Energy"** instead of **"Dual Energies"**?

> Another example: **Multi-energy** CT imaging, **multi panel** canvas set, etc.

**"Dual energy"** is also commonly written as **"dual-energy"**.

This is not the first time I notice this kind of naming method. 
The title above is just an example I found recently.

Comment: "dual energy" is name of scientific technique, ["Dual Energy"](http://www.dual-energy.co.uk/) is name of company

Comment: @A-312 It's not the name of a certain company. "Dual energy" here refers to scientific techniques that use two energies to scan an object. Hence my confusion, another example: multi-energy X-ray imaging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When used as adjectives, nouns are in general singular.  Here the noun is uncountable **scanning**, and **dual energy** is used as an adjective.

For example:

- a five metre yacht
- a two horse race
- a £10 note ("ten pound")
- some multi-site companies
- some five door cars

Some style guides prefer hyphens in the adjectival phrase, some suggest only when it is ambiguous.

- a ten-year-old child
- some five-door cars
- five thousand-person towns (five towns, each with 1,000 persons)
- a five-thousand-person town (one town, with 5,000 persons)